# Are powers of a natural number distributed widely in the residue system?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, exponentiation

I encountered the following while solving another problem and need some help.

Let $p,d$ be relatively prime natural numbers. I think that for many of $(p,d)$ tuples, numbers in set $\mathbb{N}_d = \{0,1,2,\cdots,d-1\}$ which are residue of one of the $1, p, p^2, \cdots$ modulo $d$ are kind of widely, uniformly distributed.
More precisely, let's call $n\in\mathbb{N}_d$ which there exists natural number $u$ such that $n \equiv p^u\;(\text{mod} \;d)$, a good number. Are good numbers 'widely' distributed?

What I actually need for the original problem is that, there are only few $(p,d,c)$ such that for the smallest non trivial divisor of $p$, let's say $t$, some numbers called '$c$-good numbers', which are $n\in\mathbb{N}_d$ such that there exists $u$ with $n\equiv cp^u\;(\text{mod }d)$, are all smaller than the rational number $d/t$.

This was what I mean by 'widely distributed'. Are there some known theorems or results that imply or mean the wide distribution of powers in the residue system, which may potentially be useful for the problem?

Comment: You will be interested in the *multiplicative group* modulo $d$, often written $\mathbb Z_d^*$, whose elements are the residues coprime to $d$.  The order of this group is $\varphi (d) $.  The powers of $p$ will make up a cyclic subgroup, and in the case it generates all the residues of $\mathbb Z_d^*$, we say $p$ is a *primitive element* there.

Comment: Not every $d$ will have a primitive element $p$. The ones that do are the subject of a frequently mentioned *primitive root theorem* [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1952953/primitive-root-theorem-proof)..

Comment: @hardmath I got confused, sorry. Removed my comment.

Comment: Can you phrase your question more precisely, e.g. what is "relatively few", which parameters are fixed and which are varying. The letter $p$ is a really bad choice for a non-prime number.

Comment: @user760870 I just wanted to know about some properties or conditions such $(p,d,c)$ tuples satisfy. I used the term "relatively few" because I wanted the property to rule out impossible tuples as many as possible. I'm varying all $(p,d,c)$ where $p,d$ are coprime. For use of letter $p$, sorry if it was confusing.

Comment: Yes, there are results on the uniform distribution of natural sets, such as subgroups (and sets of powers), in modular arithmetic; here is one entry point into the literature. https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2920821