# which Numbers can have primitive roots?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, totient-function, primitive-roots

I know that if $(a,n)=1,n>0$ and $a^{ϕ(n)}≡1\pmod n$, i.e, order of a $\bmod n$ is $ϕ(n)$,  then $a$ is called the *primitive root modulo $n$*.

> I want to know what are the possible values of $n$,
> i.e, which integers can have primitive roots?

> Is there any rule that only certain integers can have primitive roots?

I also realised that $n$ cannot be only prime, as $3^2≡1\pmod 4$, so that $n=4$ and $ϕ(4)=2$.

Sorry for such a basic question, but any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: The natural numbers which have a primitive root are exactly the following numbers: $2, 4$, powers of an odd prime, and $2$ times a power of an odd prime.

Comment: Dear @Arunodoy, Keep in mind that, to be a primitive root modulo $n$, $\phi(n)$ must be the *smallest* positive integer with the property that $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1\pmod{n}$.

Comment: @ Mark, thanks, I got my answer, I just wanted wanted this clarification .

Comment: @ Mark , can you please post your comment as an answer ? So that I can mark it as the answer? Thanks !

Comment: @ Keenan Kidwell, thanks for that information, I will keep that in mind :)

Comment: @ Arturo Magidin, thanks for editing my question. Can you please tell me how are these particular math functions implemented while framing my questions?

Comment: @ARUNODOY PRAMANIK Ok, I wrote it as an answer.

Comment: This has been discussed here before (more than once). Does this answer your question? [Primitive Root Theorem Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1952953/primitive-root-theorem-proof)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The natural numbers which have a primitive root are exactly the following numbers: $2,4$, powers of an odd prime and $2$ times a power of an odd prime.